# JPA/HSQLDB Persistence class not found error

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I'm pretty new to JPA and HSQLDB, and I'm havin a weird error when I'm trying to create my EntityManagerFactory. Its a Web Dynamic project in Eclipse (with Tomcat 6.0 as web server) and I imported all the libraries in the the WEB-INF/lib. I'm trying to create the Entity manager Factory in a servlet but in just gives me a class not found exception on the line

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
```

Here is the code I used in my servlet:

```
package view;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.ThemeLivre;

public class AjouterTheme extends HttpServlet {
//private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PersistenceUnit(unitName ="DB")
private EntityManagerFactory emf; 

public AjouterTheme() {
    super();        
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DB");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    String nomTheme = request.getParameter("nomtheme");
    String descTheme = request.getParameter("desctheme");
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    ThemeLivre thml = new ThemeLivre(nomTheme, descTheme);
    em.persist(thml);
    tx.commit();


}

}
```

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="1.0"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="DB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
 <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>

<class>model.ThemeLivre</class>

<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/"/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

</properties>
```

Please tell me what I did wrong, or if there is something I can do. 
Thank you

Comment: "I imported all the libraries in the the WEB-INF/lib". Could you post the libs that are under WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: The com.springsource librairies and javax.persistence_2.0.3.v201010191057.jar

Comment: Try to add the hibernate persistence provider lib. You add only the specification (API). The implementation itself (hibernate) is needed, to create an  Entity Manager.

Comment: I did add the library.. but still did not work

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet code you used

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName ="DB")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

but you declare

```
<persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

change either the one or the other persistence unit name.

Following your input above

Try to add the hibernate persistence provider lib. You add only the specification (API). The implementation itself (hibernate) is needed, to create an  Entity Manager.